# TypeScript : Cannot find namespace 'Parse' namespace error for parse in?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The issue i am having is that my react scripts is showing an error that i cannot find namespace parse which indicates their is something wrong with the configuration of my dependencies .

```
//Error in npm 

[react-scripts] Cannot find namespace 'Parse'.  TS2503
```

// My pacakge.json files my dependencies

```
{
  "name": "ionicSearchApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/app": "1.1.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "3.5.1",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "1.1.4",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "1.2.2",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "1.0.8",
    "@ionic/react": "^6.0.0",
    "@ionic/react-router": "^6.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/react": "^16.14.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.10",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.11",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "ionicons": "^5.4.0",
    "parse": "^3.4.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4",
    "workbox-background-sync": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-broadcast-update": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-cacheable-response": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-core": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-expiration": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-google-analytics": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-navigation-preload": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-precaching": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-range-requests": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-routing": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-strategies": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-streams": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns 'node_modules/(?!(@ionic/react|@ionic/react-router|@ionic/core|@stencil/core|ionicons)/)'",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "3.5.1"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

// my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I think its either a problem with the dependencies or the file  type itself as according to this article https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-cannot-find-namespace-context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `npm install` or `npm install --save @types/parse`

Answer (score 0):

The npm dependencies was missing @types/parse

Fixed by

```
 npm install --save @types/parse
```